# Discord.py How do a error message for MissingPermission

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(move_members = True)
async def move(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice.channel
    try :
        await user.move_to(channel)
        await ctx.send("Le jouer a bien été move !")
        return
    except :
        await ctx.send("Le joueur n'est pas dans un channel vocal !")
        return
```

I want the bot to send me a message in the chat when I enter in the MissingPermissions error. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Docs would be your friend :P
[More Details](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

```py
@move.error
async def move_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('MissingPermissions...')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for commands.MissingPermissions.
Add this err handle function below your command will do it.

```
@move.error
async def move_err(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'Hey! you don't have permission')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an extra bit of information, you can do the *same thing* as Guddi and Kouheng have answered, except the following code also let's you specify what permissions the user happens to be missing.

```py
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
        error_roles = error.missing_perms
        await ctx.send(f"You are missing the following permissions: {', '.join(error_roles)}")
```

[image: Above code working]